# Sharepoint 2010 Windows 8 app CRUD operations

Tags: windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am currently in the process of developing a Windows 8 (Windows Store) app that connects to a sharepoint site using the REST interface. Currently, I have successfully managed to pull down list data from the _vti_bin/ListData.svc/ uri. However, I am stuck on creating new list items from within the app, and Posting these back into sharepoint.

I am trying to use an HTTP POST method, however am receiving a 405 error code: MethodNotAllowed. Below is my code:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);


// HttpResponseMessage response = newClient.PostAsync("http://sharepoint/.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Nominations", test);
var resp = await newClient.GetAsync(newUri("http://sharepoint/.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Nominations")); 

using (newClient)
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
  var djs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NominationsItem));
  djs.WriteObject(ms, test);
  ms.Position = 0;
  var sc = new StreamContent(ms);
  sc.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

  resp = test == null
    ? await newClient.PutAsync(new Uri("http://sharepoint/.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Nominations"), sc)
    : await newClient.PostAsync(new Uri("http://sharepoint.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Nominations"), sc);

    resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!